# Facing linking error while compiling the code in keil

Tags: c, embedded, keil, stm32f4

I want to use `USART` in `stm32f446re`. I am adding the required files such as gpio.c,rcc.c,usart.c etc from the Keil folder. I am not using cubemx software.
So while compiling the files I am facing the error that #include "stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h" is missing.

I guess the problem is while linking. Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

After adding the the conf.h file as suggested in below answers.I am facing these new erorrs:[image]

Comment: _"I guess the problem is while linking"_. No, it's a compilation error. Where does the header file exist on your computer?

Comment: @RaVi DuDi "adding the required files" - Why you adopted this approach of adding only few files ?  What is that you are going to get by doing this ? Even if you add all required .h files, You end up using HAL apis of STM32. and in future upgradation to latest HAL layer may become difficult and time taking process.So, either you may use HAL layer as a whole.Or Write your own simple code if only USART communication is required.

Comment: @Babajan  I just want to use usart.I don't need too many extra files.I wanted to do it manually by importing as less files as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file named `stm32f4xx_hal_conf_template.h` in the STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Inc folder.  As the name implies, that file is a template.  You're supposed to copy that file into your project folder and rename it to `stm32f4xx_hal_conf.h`.  You can edit the copy to configure the HAL appropriately for your project.

Review some of the example projects included with STM32CubeF4 package to see how the template include file is copied and customized.

Comment: Thanks.That worked but now i am facing 6 more erorrs after adding conf.h file.         
Such as                                                                                                       .\Objects\Usart.axf: Error: L6218E: Undefined symbol HAL_NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping (referred from stm32f4xx_hal.o).